# Received Facebook error response of type CurlException

Tags: java, facebook-opengraph, restfb

When I publish an action (as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#publish), sometimes I'm receiving a cURL error from Facebook:

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookGraphException: Received Facebook error response of type CurlException: cURL Error [#22, CURLE_HTTP_NOT_FOUND]: Transfer failed
```

I'm using the com.restfb lib in Java. Most of the time, this works perfectly.

Any idea?

**MAY 3 UPDATE**

Ok, I've probably found a solution. Each times I receive a 'CURLE_HTTP_NOT_FOUND', my 'og:image' content was an url sending '404 not found' HTTP error. This is a bug.

I will fix it, and be back soon ;)